# Text to Speech in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, text-to-speech

I would like to do some japanese text to speech on my dedicated windows 2003 x64 server with .net framework, using c#
I found something on google, but requires to install a lot of files on the server... i don't like, for stability issues: there is another option, like a linked dll or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a ASP.NET application converting text to speech](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716447/creating-a-asp-net-application-converting-text-to-speech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using SAPI in an ASP.NET website, is impossible: the sound will be reproduced on the server :S

It seems that there is the need of [Microsoft Speech Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Speech_Server)
...
Or not? With asp.net is possible to run a commandline exe on the server to save an mp3, then stream that mp3, right? (how to do that? i will try to figure it)
I will go this way, i let you know the result :)

**edit:** this is how i solved:
[How to save text-to-speech as a wav with Microsoft SAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963503/how-to-save-text-to-speech-as-a-wav-with-microsoft-sapi/963536#963536)

I save the generated voice in a wav file, then i embed it on the page, playing it in a flash player
COOL!!

Comment: i could use SAPI and save the stream on a file, and then embed that file in the webpage. cool, later i will try

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Microsoft Speech SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e86ec97-40a7-453f-b0ee-6583171b4530&displaylang=en). It's a set of COM APIs containing TTS and SR engines. I'm not sure if it contains Japanese TTS though.

Comment: there is a language pack for japanese and chinese in the link that you posted, i'll take a look if i can use it
thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you most likely want is the [Microsoft Speech Server](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/evaluation/tools/default.mspx) especially if your webite is going to encounter any decent load or volume.

From the site:

> "A speech platform, MSS contains all
>   the server components for deploying
>   telephony (voice-only) and multimodal
>   (voice/visual) applications. MSS
>   combines Web technologies,
>   speech-processing services, and
>   telephony capabilities into a single
>   system. "

There is also a dedicated [Microsft Speech community](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/community/default.mspx) which will likely help you get started in this realm.  Also, I'm not sure what the latest version is...2004 R2?

[This article](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/community/newsletter/articles/0805article.htm) has a decent diagram outlining the various components.  Looks like a good fit for integration with an ASP Web Application.

Comment: but the app that i am doing if for my personal web site (hence, free).
It looks like Microsoft Speech Server is gonna be expensive, and no, pirating it is not an option, as i am hosting my personal website on the company server :P What limitations have the free Microsoft Speech Server Developer Edition? I haven't figured it out. (BTW, 2gb of stuff for saying the correct pronunciation in my free asp.net language course, it kinda out of the question: i cannot monopolize the company server :-P

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Speech Library and see this article [**Text to Speech with the Microsoft Speech Library and SDK version 5.1**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/TTSinVBpackage.aspx) in CodeProject. Also see [**Giving Computers a Voice**](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2006/10/31/909044.aspx) in Coding4Fun

Answer (score 0):

The [System.Speech.Synthesis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis(lowband).aspx) namespace has been part of the framework since .NET 3.0. However, it has internal dependencies on the Speech SDK COM libraries (it chooses the correct version depending on the host OS), so I would recommend prototyping the work before you jump in.

The class you should probably look at first is [System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx) ([whitepaper and example code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx))

**Warning:**  I have personally experienced issues using the speech APIs in an ASP.NET environment whereby the request that returned the audio data never returned. Despite heavy debugging I was never able to resolve the issue and the feature was dropped. I have had an unresolved support case with Microsoft for 12 months now.