# Text to Speech in ASP.NET - Access is denied... what to do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2003, text-to-speech

On my personal website, i would like to make it "pronounce" something

I solved the "concept" problem, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961546/text-to-speech-in-asp-net), and on my desktop it works smoothly when launched from visual web developer. Creates a file, and then an embedded player in the page will play it. Perfect.

So, I uploaded it on the server... I get this error 500:

> Server Error in '/sapi' Application.
>   Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
>   used if the application is not
>   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity
>   will be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> (...)
>
> Source Error:
>
> See it below
>
> Source File:
>   c:\mypath\sapi\myfile.aspx.cs
>   Line: 21
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))]
>   SpeechLib.SpVoiceClass.Speak(String
>   Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags Flags) +0 
>   prova.Button1_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in
>   c:\mypath\sapi\prova.aspx.cs:21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +13    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053

This is the source

Source Error:

Line 19: `myfile.Open(@"C:\mypath\sapi\gen\hi.wav",SpeechStreamFileMode.SSFMCreateForWrite,false);`

Line 20: `voice.AudioOutputStream = myfile;`

**Line 21:** `voice.Speak("Hi",SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);`

I get error on line 21, Voice.speak

That probably means that the aspnet worker user has not some right permission

The generation folder has all the right permissions: an empty file is created.

So, i have to give permission of execute to some system dll?

Do you know which dll? It is **not** `bin\Interop.SpeechLib.dll`, on this one the aspnet user has full control

Ps: i have full control on the (windows) server (i mean, access by RDC, is not a shared hosting)

Comment: I think you should consider the possibility that the problem _is_ the file access. I wouldn't rule it out, given that the actual file access is being performed by a piece of COM code, possibly running out of process?

Comment: if i deny write permissions on the output folder, i get another exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND)), so that's why i think the problems is that the aspnet user hasn't the right persmission to run the sapi voice...

Comment: also, the wav is created, and it contains the wav header: RIFF&_____WAVEfmt____data but not the file stream, so it looks like the dll to make it "fill", is blocked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a ASP.NET application converting text to speech](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716447/creating-a-asp-net-application-converting-text-to-speech)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by setting the AppPool as working as "Local System" and by setting in the machine.config to work as SYSTEM account

Of course i feel that as a security issue, as i am hosting my personal website on the (small) company server (Employees are explicitly authorized to do so by the company owner)

Maybe this is not a good solution?

I set this setting only for this webapp, and i am not so good at coding (so there are lots of bugs in my code, measured in [100 WTFs/minute](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m) (haha)

Comment: I think because the default ASPNET user has "guest" privileges, (if i am right), so **maybe**, running it as local system, will allow to run system files

Comment: Can you please explain how you did this? I have exactly the same issue that I am unable to resolve. I did set the AppPool to run as "Local System" and it did not help

Comment: well, i am not sure what i did, i am quite a noob.
i think that bin\Interop.SpeechLib.dll must have the right permissions for the working process user

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar problems, after many headaches i did manage to solve the issue with me. I found two problems the first being the browser, i found for my purpose only ie explorer would work and not other browsers such as mozilla. The second problem was finally the permissions, even though i had all permissions correctly i found that i had to remove the internet user permission and check the log on as local account option which then worked.