# Interop.SpeechLib.dll COM Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net, text-to-speech, sapi

I am using SpeechLib for a very simple text to voice conversion. Works great locally. When I deploy the applcation on to the server, I get the exception:

```
could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030002 (STG_E_FILENOTFOUND))
```

I have done the following with no luck:

- Set the AppPool to run using the
  LocalSystem
- Have given write priveleges to the folder where SpeechLib creates the
  wav file

I have exactly the same issue by users at:

[User1](http://forums.asp.net/t/1422990.aspx)

[User2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022356/text-to-speech-in-asp-net-access-is-denied-what-to-do)

Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you to use `System.Speech` namespace (in `System.Speech` assembly)?

Comment: No, I did try that but ran into a whole bunch of other issues. Getting System.Speech to work with a web application opens up quite a few issues

Comment: Also related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716447/creating-a-asp-net-application-converting-text-to-speech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall Windows Server to get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I think the important question here is *to whom* have you given the rights to the folder where SpeechLib creates the wav file and *who* exactly is the request running as (are you impersonating someone possibly?  Are you set up to run as someone else)?

That being said, more info is definitely needed, but I get the impression you are not assigning the permissions to the output folder correctly.

The second link that you gave on SO has an accepted answer.  That also suggests to me it is a permissions issue as well.

Comment: The file is created but its only 1kb which i think has only header info. If i had incorrect permissions to the output folder, wuld the file still be created?

Comment: @unknown (yahoo): It doesn't matter what the size of the file or the contents are, if the user trying to write the file doesn't have permissions, the operation is going to fail.

Comment: The folder where ASPNET writes files have full rights for this user account.