# ASP.NET text to speech error

Tags: asp.net, text, speech

I am using asp text to speech. it is working on my computer bu when I upload its to server it gives me following error.. I searched on internet. People suggest

```
Defaultapppoll>>Properties>>Identity>>Predefine>>Local System And Restart IIS
```

I did it but still not working... help please..
 my local pc and my server has 64 bit cpu...

The error is :

```
Server Error in '/domepage' Application.

Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004503A
```

Description:

> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004503A
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[COMException (0x8004503a): Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004503A]
   SpeechLib.ISpeechVoice.Speak(String Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags Flags) +0
   demo.pop_up_dictionary.img_dictionary_text_to_speech_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in c:\Users\mehmet\Desktop\06-08\demo\pop_up_dictionary.aspx.cs:39
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +134
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18010

Comment: yes I am using asp.net, sorry for mistake...

Comment: Then are you restart your iis ?

Comment: I restated IIS my times...

Comment: @mbultraslan did you fix this ?  how ? i have this issue in a winform application. will this error be thrown if i dont have any audio devices like speakers connected ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a ASP.NET application converting text to speech](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716447/creating-a-asp-net-application-converting-text-to-speech)

Answer (score 0):

```
Defaultapppoll>>Properties>>Identity>>Predefine>>Local System

 And >>**Restart IIS**
```

Did you restart your iis ?

**Edit**:

This is something related with the user account running the application. If you running the application on the IIS, the account is Network Service in IIS6.0 and ASPNET in IIS5.0. The two account doesn't hava access right to the SpeechLib. You should modify the account which is running the Web application.

If you are using IIS6.0, there is a application pool which your web application exists in. Change the identity of the Application Pool to Loal System and then your application will run.

Comment: Sorry . I don't know . I think Anyone does not help here . Please ask this question is here : http://forums.asp.net/26.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had no sound drivers installed or configured. no playback devices installed in a server and had this issue. after installing sound driver and set volume it worked i was able to hear the sound.