# Microsoft Speech Object Library error: 80040154 ASP.NET Web Form Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, text-to-speech, microsoft-speech-platform

I'm trying to use Text-to-speech for ASP.NET Web Form Application `using SpeechLib;`:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
   SpVoice voice = new SpVoice();
   voice.Speak("hello");            
}
```

in Reference Manager COM I have three versions of Microsoft Speech Object Library

```
5.4 File Version 5.3.14393.351 (rs1_release_inmarket.161014-1755)
5.4 File Version 5.3.19915.00 (rs1_release.160715-1616) 
11.0.14405.00 built by: scg_2011_w1m3_beta(rtbldlab)
```

So I have just add it all, but seems like 5.3.19915.00 does not works, anyway I can call `using SpeechLib;` but I got error:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
>   with CLSID {Registry Key} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repair COMException error 80040154?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197506/how-to-repair-comexception-error-80040154)

Comment: Usually it is an architecture mismatch. 32bit vs 64bit.

Comment: And overall, it is not going to work anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716447/creating-a-asp-net-application-converting-text-to-speech